# What is the Exact Definition of a Whole Number?

Tags: definition

I have thought about this for a long time, since I have done some Grade 8 American Math League (A Competition) Past Papers, but when it asked some question like: How many whole numbers have their square less than or equal to $200$, I thought any integer from $-14$ to $14$ works, which is $29$ whole numbers, but the answer says there are only $15$. I then searched up the definition of whole numbers, and most of the sites said they were nonnegative integers, while others just say a whole number is any integer.

But if a whole number is a nonnegative integer, then why do questions like "Round $-3.6$ to the nearest whole number" exist?

I've discussed this question with my teacher and even the Head of Mathematics of my school, but they both said that a whole number is any integer. My maths teacher also said that we only would talk about integers and not whole numbers in High School, but I am still curious about what a whole number actually is.

Thank you very much!

Comment: A whole number is an element of $\mathbb{Z}=\{0,\pm 1, \pm 2,\dotso\}$. So nothing special here. I would guess that the solution in the answer is just a typo.

Comment: The question about squares less than 200 should/could have specified the range of possible solutions: positive, non-negative etc.

Comment: Thank you, but I think in most websites, it states that it is a nonnegative number, so I am not exactly sure about this. One website is: https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/whole-number.html

Comment: True, it just said "whole numbers"

Comment: I also think that the term "whole number" is never really defined. The common way is to talk about integers in the english language. As a native german I would say "ganze Zahl" (whole number). So I think that the term originated from the german. That is where the notation $\mathbb{Z}$ from Zahl (=number) come from. So it might be more or less just a way of communicating. A synonym for integer.

Comment: Thank you Cornman!

Comment: @CheeseCake "*Whole number*" is whatever it was defined to be in the context you are working in, nothing more and nothing less. It does not have a rigorous, universally accepted definition. See for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number): "*the meaning is ambiguous. It may refer to either...*".

Comment: True, I saw that and forgot to mention it

Comment: @CheeseCake I do not think that the website "mathisfun.org" is a reliable source. I can not recollect a single time where a "whole number" was defined in a textbook.

Comment: @Cornman I'm not sure if the link I attached below is a textbook, but it is defined as a nonnegative integer in an indirect way. http://www.opentextbookstore.com/arithmetic/book.pdf

Comment: @dxiv, I think your comment would be good as an answer.

Comment: @CheeseCake Might be. Keep in mind that for some authors we have $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,\dotso\}$. Others let $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dotso\}$. Stuff like this exists a lot in mathematics. It is as dxiv says. Probably in context of the competition a "whole number" was defined.

Comment: @Cornman That is true, as in Australia we have natural numbers as positive integers, and PROBABLY whole numbers as all integers.

Comment: @MeesdeVries There have been several helpful comments for the OP to draw their own conclusion, and perhaps post it as a self-answer.

Comment: A whole number doesn't have any pieces left over like fractions. This is really a question for Sesame Street.

Comment: The definition of an integer is not ambigous. And usually, a whole number is nothing else than an integer. If natural numbers (with or without $0$) or nonnegative whole numbers are meant, it would be better to state this explicite. Whether $0$ belongs to the natural number is another story. There seems to be no convention about this.

Comment: Honestly, this is the first time I've ever heard that a "whole number" might be negative. I'd thought it always meant "nonnegative integer".

Comment: I was sure that "whole numbers" and integers are synonyms. Until this discussion [Why don’t American school textbooks recognize negative numbers as whole numbers?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18948/why-don-t-american-school-textbooks-recognize-negative-numbers-as-whole-numbers), where I learnt that there is no such consensus. Now I just avoid using this phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days, I saw that in the Australian Textbook Year 11 Extension 1 Chapter 2A that whole numbers are nonnegative integers.

Thank you for your help!